# How add class='current-menu-item' to html menu with php in smarty .tpl file

Tags: smarty

I have header.tpl file to be included in my whole website running Smarty. I need a php-if code that make certain navigation menu element to take class 'current-menu-item' when the page is active in the browser.

```
<ul>
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/dbk/index.php">Home</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Company</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/about.php">About Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/team.php">Excuslive Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/global-business.php">Global Business</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/contract-manufacturing.php">Contract Manufacturing</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Our Products</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/pharmaceutical-products.php">Pharmaceutical Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/products/herbal-and-food.php">Herbal & Food Supplements</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/products/cosmetics.php">Cosmetics</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/products/veterinary-products.php">Veterinary Products</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/blog">News Room</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/careers.php">Careers</a> </li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/dbk/contacts.php">Contacts</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just through a local assigned tpl variable, i.e :

```
<li {if $page == "about"}class="current-menu-item"{/if}><a href="http://localhost/dbk/about.php">About Company</a></li> 
<li {if $page == "team"}class="current-menu-item"{/if}><a href="http://localhost/dbk/team.php">Excuslive Team</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

### How I did it

in the PHP script, do something like `$smarty->assign("curPage", $currentPage);` (`$currentPage` is set through `$_GET` or your way).

And I use this in my template file:

```
{foreach from=$aMenu key=key item=value}
    {assign var="class" value=""}
    {if $curPage == $value}
        {assign var="class" value=" class='current-menu-item'"}
    {/if}

    <li{$class}><a href="/{$value}">{$key}</a></li>
{/foreach}
```

### In steps explained

1. First I start the foreach loop, to loop over all my menu elements (set through PHP).
2. Assign the `class` variable, empty.
3. Check if the `curPage` (remember `$currentPage` from PHP?) matches the current foreach loop item
4. If yes, set the item to selected (using `class='current-menu-item'`).
5. Finally output the `<li>` element.